# Database design for custom structure

Tags: database, database-design

I need to allow users to have custom tables in my applications (I'm using PostgreSQL). Expected size of custom user data is very big so I'm looking for data base oriented solution:

Users can make table, delete table, add or remove data......

I thinking of following options:

a) To make additional tables in my application DB schema (each starting with some prefix, for different users).

b) To make separate schema in same data base as my application in witch table names will start with some prefix, for different users

c) To make 1 separate database and many different schema (for different users)

d) To make new data base for every user (there will be < 100 users who can make custom tables)

e) To make new instance of DB server and there implement solution a)

f) To instance new HSQL server and there save custom user data. I'm thinking that user custom data will be smaller than 1GB per user, and having DB in memory would speed things up

Solutions a) - e) are for PostgreSQL

Any thoughts? What would you choose? **Something else**?

Comment: How will users be creating database tables?  Will they be manually executing SQL, or will this all occur is some obfuscated way (such as with LINQ or something like it)?  How big exactly would each user's database be?  "Very big" is relative.

Comment: user will create tables trough my gui. max table size: maybe 10 columns and 1 million rows

Comment: Is the data in all of these different schemas compatible?  Is there any reason all of these schemas cannot exist as a single schema with tables partitioned by user?

Comment: tables can be in single schema. in that case i'm worried about performance issues. i'm not sure can user custom tables cause a high CPU usage on db server

Comment: I can't speak to PostgreSQL performance in this case, but if this were Oracle and you know the user data well enough to create the tables in advance, reference-partitioning your schema by user would allow for good performance with fewer administrative headaches and more control.